# React wait for data fetch and then render

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, axios

So I'm trying fetch data with axios, process it and then render as an option in React select.
I will put bellow sections of my code to make it easier to understand.

```
const [data1, setData1] = useState([]);
const [data2, setData2] = useState([]);
const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url, {
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                setData1(response.data);
            }
        })
        .catch((response) => {

        });

    axios.get(url, {
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                setData2(response.data);
            }
        })
        .catch((response) => {

        });   


    data1.map(info1 => {
        let y = data2.filter(info2 => {
            return info1.id == info2.id
        })

        let z = y.map(user => {
            return { value: user, label: user.username }
        });
        
        setOptions(y);
    })
}, []);
```

And this is the rendering

```
<select value={selectedOption} onChange={handleChange} className='w-40'>
            {options.map((option) => {
                return (
                    <option value={option.value}>
                        {option.label}
                    </option>)
            })}
</select>
```

But it's just giving me an empty select. I understand that my useEffect will run a single time after the render it's done and I should use async/await somehow but I don't understand where. I used const state [render, setReder] for conditional rendering but still won't work.

How should I use async/await?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Maybe you want to change `setOptions(y);` to `setOptions(z);`?

Comment: Even if you `await` the axios requests, updating the state is an asynchronous process as well so `data1` and `data2` still might not have been updated yet by the time `data1.map()` runs. I personally would move the `data1.map()` process to a separate `useEffect` that is dependent on changes to `data1` and `data2`.

Comment: Yeah, when I put the code on stackoverflow i forgot to modify it. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I think you should split your `useEffect` in two:

```
const [data1, setData1] = useState([]);
const [data2, setData2] = useState([]);
const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url, {
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                setData1(response.data);
            }
        })
        .catch((response) => {

        });

    axios.get(url, {
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                setData2(response.data);
            }
        })
        .catch((response) => {

        });   
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    data1.map(info1 => {
        let y = data2.filter(info2 => {
            return info1.id == info2.id
        })

        let z = y.map(user => {
            return { value: user, label: user.username }
        });
        
        setOptions(z);
    });
}, [data1, data2]);
```

This way, the `options` are updated whenever `data1` or `data2` are modified.

Updating `options` will trigger a re-render of your select options.

From a stylistic point of view, `data1.map` should probably be `data1.forEach` and keep in mind that your current loop assumes `data1` only contains a single entry.

I don't know what sort of data you're dealing with, but this might be more accurate:

```
    const newOptions = [];

    data1.forEach(info1 => {
        let y = data2.filter(info2 => {
            return info1.id == info2.id
        })

        let z = y.map(user => {
            return { value: user, label: user.username }
        });
        
        newOptions.push(...z);
    });

    setOptions(newOptions);
```

Comment: useEffect renders twice because dependencies [data1,data2] of useEffect

Comment: @OkanKaradag Yes, but that shouldn’t be a problem. I do not know if the Ajax calls can return empty arrays. It would be an easy fix to return early without calling `setOptions` if either array is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do conditional rendering in React is pretty simple.
Usually involves checking some value and basing the render upon the result.

**Example:**

```
if (options.length === 0) {
   return <></>;
}

return (
   <select value={selectedOption} onChange={handleChange} className='w-40'>
      {options.map((option) => (
         <option value={option.value}>
            {option.label}
         </option>)
      }))
   </select>
)
```

Or it can also be inlined.
**Like so:**

```
return (
   {options.length === 0 ? (
      <></>
   ) : (
   <select value={selectedOption} onChange={handleChange} className='w-40'>
      {options.map((option) => (
         <option value={option.value}>
            {option.label}
         </option>)
      }))
   </select>
))
```

**Note:** This example is based on checking the value of `options`, the same method can be used for other states and variables as-well.

---

### Edit:

Also, what you are trying to achieve here will likely not work since `setState` in React acts like an `async` function.
Meaning that by the time you try to map over the value of `data1` in the `useEffect`, `data1` has likely not finished updating yet and still holds the previous value.

In order to do this properly in this case you can simply map over the value of `response.data` instead.

**Example:**

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url, {
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status == 200) {
               setData1(response.data);
               response.data.map(info1 => {
               let y = data2.filter(info2 => {
                  return info1.id == info2.id
               })

               // Side-note: I don't understand why `z` is needed here if not used.
               let z = y.map(user => {
                  return { value: user, label: user.username }
               });

               setOptions(y);
               })
            }
        })
        .catch((response) => {

        });

    axios.get(url, {
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                setData2(response.data);
            }
        })
        .catch((response) => {

        });   
}, []);
```

**PS:** see if you even need `data1` / `data2` in this case.
I would suggest to just try and make it a single object, etc..

Comment: `data1` return empty so not change if data1 call immediatly after `setData1(response.data)`

Comment: You're right, my bad. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use async/await in your code as follows

```
const [data1, setData1] = useState([]);
const [data2, setData2] = useState([]);
const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

const fetchData = async() => {
  const response1 = axios.get(url)
  if (response1.status == 200) {
     setData1(response1.data);
  }
 const response2 = axios.get(url)
 if (response2.status == 200) {
    setData2(response2.data);
 }
}

useEffect(() => {  
  fetchData();
}, []);
useEffect(()=>{
if(data1.length > 0 && data2.length > 0){
    data1.map(info1 => {
        let y = data2.filter(info2 => {
            return info1.id == info2.id
        })

        let z = y.map(user => {
            return { value: user, label: user.username }
        });
        
        setOptions(z);
    })
}
},[data1, data2])
```

And in the render function

```
{options.length > 0 && <select value={selectedOption} onChange={handleChange} 
className='w-40'>
            {options.map((option) => {
                return (
                    <option value={option.value}>
                        {option.label}
                    </option>)
            })}
</select>}
```

Comment: it wont run setOptions if `data2` return empty

Comment: A check can be added for `z` to verify if array has value @OkanKaradag

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use another useEffect with data1 and data2 dependencies. So when data1 and data2 change, this function will be called and inside it, you can calculate options.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    data1.map(info1 => {
        let y = data2.filter(info2 => {
            return info1.id == info2.id
        })

        let z = y.map(user => {
            return { value: user, label: user.username }
        });
    
        setOptions(z);
    })

}, [data1, data2])
```

and also in the rendering part, you should check if the options data is available, render it. otherwise, show loading or something else.

```
return (
   {options && options.length === 0 ? (
      <Loading />
   ) : (
   <select value={selectedOption} onChange={handleChange} className='w-40'>
      {options.map((option) => (
         <option value={option.value}>
            {option.label}
         </option>)
      }))
   </select>
))
```

also for parallel request, I think it's better to use `promise.all` like this example:

```
function getUserAccount() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345');
}

function getUserPermissions() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345/permissions');
}

Promise.all([getUserAccount(), getUserPermissions()])
  .then(function (results) {
    const acct = results[0];
    const perm = results[1];
  });
```